# How to fix the issue where the variant is not finding the product while normalizing cart in framework/spree of V1?

Tags: next.js, spree, storefront

I'm using commerce v1 with spree as backend.  When the user is not logged in and add something to cart  using  `useAddItem` hook it's returning error while normalizing cart **Couldn't find product for variant with id**  even though the variant and product are related.Providing related code below

```
 const product = jsonApi.findSingleRelationshipDocument<ProductAttr>(
    spreeSuccessResponse,
    variant,
    'product'
  )

  if (product === null) {
    throw new MissingLineItemVariantError(
      `Couldn't find product for variant with id ${variant.id}.`
    )
  }
```

The item is added to cart  its just throwing error while normalizing it and that's only for guest user.